# Выход из приложения

Tags: android

Ребята, нужно организовать выход из приложения не с MainActivity, а активности, запущенной, второй, третьей и т.д.
При использовании нижепредставленного кода выход осуществляется в предыдущую активность.. 
Пользуюсь следующим кодом:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Внимание!")
                .setMessage("Вы действительно хотите выйти?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Activity2.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
```

Comment: В системе Андроид нет понятия "выход из приложения", есть завершения акивностей. Как только последняя завершится, приложение исчезнет с экрана (но никак не завершится). Именно приложение завершить может только система (легальным способом конечно).

Comment: Есть такой метод `Activity.finishAffinity()` - он закрывает все активности, но только с `API16`

Comment: Вы имеете в виду выход из приложения при нажатии кнопки Back? (cудя по коду)

Comment: да, по кнопке Back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Завершить все активити кроме первой:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

И добавьте в `OnCreate` первой активити:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && 
getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("EXIT", false)) {
finish();
}
```

Comment: Добавлю, что `FirstActivity` должна находиться в стеке (в самом низу), иначе ничего не получится.

Comment: что-то не получается.. снова выбрасывает ан эту же активность

Comment: Вернее, выбрасывает на FirstActivity, которая продолжает работать и отображаться на экране

Comment: вы в FirstActivity в OnCreate добавили что я написал?

Comment: Конечно. Просто не отрабатывается завершение первой активности, продолжают выполняться действия, запланированные кодом первой активности